# How to escape dollar sign ($) in emmet?

Tags: html, emmet

As emmet use dollar sign ($) for numbering like:

```
p#p${$}*3  //outputs <p id="p1">1</p><p id="p2">2</p><p id="p3">3</p>
```

it has its significant usefulness.

But, in case of currency, I am having strange problem with it.

```
p{$10} //outputs <p>${14}</p> expected <p>$10</p>
```

What can I do for this type of scenario?

**Note:** To be precise, I am using https://github.com/Krizz/jquery.emmet as jquery emmet plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try and use `&#36;`? This should escape it properly.

Source: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0024/index.htm

Comment: It works but I had to give a space between. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have figured out that the proper ending with semicolon, indeed solved the  necessity of space between. Proper answer is `p{&#36;10} //Outputs <p>$10</p>`

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that, good on you, and thanks for sharing! (I've updated the answer for future references)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\` to escape `$` symbol:

`p#p${\$}*3`

Comment: Thanks for attempting to answer the question. Unfortunately the above method didn't work in this case. `p#p${\$}*3  //outputs <p id="p1">1</p><p id="p2">2</p><p id="p3">3</p>`

Comment: This is how it works in official Emmet implementations, you can even try it on docs page: http://docs.emmet.io You might be using unofficial implementations like in WebStorm or Vim

Comment: I knew I could escape $ with backslash and now I am sure it is the official way, thanks to you sharing the link. But in this particular case, which involve https://github.com/Krizz/jquery.emmet which enabled me writing emmet code with jquery, although unofficial, the answer provided by @Roberrrt is helpful.

Comment: not working if `p#p{\$123}` Giving output `<p id="p">\</p>`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Editplus (editplus.com) but now I solve it by doubling "\"

```
"m": "\\$_=1|;include('m.php');"
```

Now transform in `$_=1;include('m.php');` with the cursor replacing "|" where is located.

Before this the result was  1_=2;include('m.php');  with "m": "\$_=1|;include('m.php');"

I use this facility to evolve some dynamic ways to a php 7.1+ version - php framework I wrote, the fastest in the world (I already benchmarked it)