# How to use $ in emmet

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Hi I want to display $123,456.00 in a span. I tried with `span{$123,456.00}` and it is expanding to `<span>,456.00</span>` *(I understand $ is used to render index in loop)*. How can I escape $ in emmet so I can get expansion `<span>123,456.00</span>`

Editor: Visual Studio Code

System: Mac OS Sierra

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39973270/how-to-escape-dollar-sign-in-emmet

Comment: @suraj Already tried, none of the answers are working. :(

Comment: which editor are you using?

Comment: @suraj, Visual Studio Code 1.16.0 on Mac OS Sierra

Comment: hah.. I happened to try this in the _same_ environment and didn't work. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34216) is the issue I raised

Comment: you might want add your editor details into the question

Comment: Great, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Emmet Docs](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/#escaping--and--characters),

> The $ character is used for tabstops and variables, the | character it used to indicate caret position when snippet is expanded. If you want to output these characters as-is, you should use double backslash to escape them: `\\$` or `\\|`

So ,

<strike>`span{\\$123,456.00}` should work.</strike>

It seems Visual Studio Code has a bug and I have raised [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34216) to track it.

**Update**

Seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/68040fa300a61f047f472ad435ed30a1ac55a7cf).

According to the developer:

> A single escape will work in tonight's Insiders.

So, `span{\$123,456.00}` should work in the next update of the editor.